# I cant get file with 'fs' and file path

Tags: javascript, file, path, fs

I dont know why but when i want see if file exist in other folder or path it return false. I tryed with **../** and **/**.

I check if file exits with:

```
const path = '../asd.txt';

if (fs.existsSync(path) {
  console.log("exist!");
}
```

I dont know why no work, anyone can help me? I tryed on windows and linux ubuntu vps and return the same problem.

Comment: is this on node? you might want to use `path.resolve` to ensure the current file path is what you expect

Comment: I used `path.resolve` and it return false.

Comment: @zLowyG - [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathresolvepaths) never returns a boolean.

Comment: I realized just now, and the path returns wrong. I need `F:\_DiscordBots\HyWy\NewHyWy\asd.txt` and the resolve returns `F:\_DiscordBots\HyWy\asd.txt` hmmm why? haha

Comment: Is your js file in ``F:\_DiscordBots\HyWy\NewHyWy\``? In that case you'd have to use `./asd.txt`

Comment: No the file is in `F:\_DiscordBots\HyWy\NewHyWy\commands/testcommand.js`

Comment: Okay, i fixed it, i only changed `../asd.txt` to `../NewHyWy/asd.txt` and it work. Now i know how i can use this. Thank you all